# Parse String to create objects using Regex in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I have an input list of strings, which I'd like to translate to list of objects using regex. In the code below, I am not creating the objects but printing them to `stdout` for simplicity.

I am able to support some of the input strings but not the entire list. Can someone share what am I doing wrong?

```scala
  lazy val TIMESTAMP_PATTERN: Regex = """(year|month|day|hour)\(([a-zA-Z_]+)[,]?([a-zA-Z_]*)\)""".r
  lazy val BUCKET_PATTERN: Regex = """(bucket)\((.+)(,)(.+)[,]?(.*)\)""".r

  Seq(
    "year(timestamp)",
    "year(timestamp, _MY_YEAR)",
    "month(timestamp)",
    "month(timestamp, _MY_MONTH)",
    "day(timestamp)",
    "day(timestamp, _MY_DAY)",
    "hour(timestamp)",
    "hour(timestamp, _MY_HOUR)",
    "bucket(id, 32)",
    "bucket(id, 32, _MY_BUCKET)",
  ).foreach { input => input match {
      case TIMESTAMP_PATTERN(transform, sourceColumn, targetColumn) => println(s"$transform ::: $sourceColumn :::- $targetColumn")
      case BUCKET_PATTERN(sourceColumn, numBuckets) => println(s"bucket ::: $sourceColumn ::: $numBuckets")
      case BUCKET_PATTERN(sourceColumn, numBuckets, targetColumn) => println(s"bucket ::: $sourceColumn ::: $numBuckets ::: $targetColumn")
      case z => println(s"Unexpected match: $z")
    }
  }
```

**Output**

```scala
year ::: timestamp :::- 
Unexpected match: year(timestamp, _MY_YEAR)
month ::: timestamp :::- 
Unexpected match: month(timestamp, _MY_MONTH)
day ::: timestamp :::- 
Unexpected match: day(timestamp, _MY_DAY)
hour ::: timestamp :::- 
Unexpected match: hour(timestamp, _MY_HOUR)
Unexpected match: bucket(id, 32)
Unexpected match: bucket(id, 32, _MY_BUCKET)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few fixes in your regexps and matching :

```
lazy val TIMESTAMP_PATTERN: Regex = """(year|month|day|hour)\((\w+)(?:,\s+)?(\w*)\)""".r
lazy val BUCKET_PATTERN: Regex = """bucket\((\w+),(?:\s+)?(\w+)(?:,\s+)?(\w*)\)""".r

  Seq(
    "year(timestamp)",
    "year(timestamp, _MY_YEAR)",
    "month(timestamp)",
    "month(timestamp, _MY_MONTH)",
    "day(timestamp)",
    "day(timestamp, _MY_DAY)",
    "hour(timestamp)",
    "hour(timestamp, _MY_HOUR)",
    "bucket(id, 32)",
    "bucket(id, 32, _MY_BUCKET)",
  ).foreach {
    case TIMESTAMP_PATTERN(transform, sourceColumn, "") => println(s"$transform ::: $sourceColumn")
    case TIMESTAMP_PATTERN(transform, sourceColumn, targetColumn) => println(s"$transform ::: $sourceColumn :::- $targetColumn")
    case BUCKET_PATTERN(sourceColumn, numBuckets, "") => println(s"bucket ::: $sourceColumn ::: $numBuckets")
    case BUCKET_PATTERN(sourceColumn, numBuckets, targetColumn) => println(s"bucket ::: $sourceColumn ::: $numBuckets ::: $targetColumn")
    case z => println(s"Unexpected match: $z")
  }
```

The output now is:

```
year ::: timestamp
year ::: timestamp :::- _MY_YEAR
month ::: timestamp
month ::: timestamp :::- _MY_MONTH
day ::: timestamp
day ::: timestamp :::- _MY_DAY
hour ::: timestamp
hour ::: timestamp :::- _MY_HOUR
bucket ::: id ::: 32
bucket ::: id ::: 32 ::: _MY_BUCKET
```

Here are the changes I made:

- Added `?:` to groups consisting of `,`s and white spaces to make those groups non-capturing. With this method, the white spaces are still optional but will not affect the end matching.
- Removed () from *bucket* so it is not a capture group
- Since the last match is optional and can be empty, modified the pattern with fewer items to match this case. Note that if the last column is not present, its capture group will be empty.